# Create group/role in wso2 IS with SCIM to ldap

Tags: ldap, wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

In WSo2 Is I have 2 user stores. one primary second for ldap I tried to create a group with SCIM to ldap
I went through http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.in/2012/11/wso2-identity-server-as-scim-service.html.

succeeded for user creation to ldap(gave "userName": "ldap/testuser") , group creation to primary store also succeeded. But group creation to LDAP fails ("displayName": "ldap\engineer") with syntax error.

Comment: Could you please let us know the error error message (stackrace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting syntax error something like following. There can be an issue in decoding the JSON request that you have send.

> Request is unparseable, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema

When multiple user stores are used. You may use the "/" character to separate the domain in your JSON request. Then you can not use double quotes with the user/role name. You need to use single quotes. Such  as following

> --data "{"schemas":[],"userName":'foo/user1',"password":"test"}"

Also in your request, It has been used the "\" character which is not the domain separator.

> ("displayName": "ldap\engineer")

For further investigation,  you can update the question with exact error.

Comment: Another issue is how to create a user for a specific tenant. I tried using the tenant admin id, password, but did not work, tried including the tenant domain in the displayName as “ldap/tenant1/xyz” and did not work.

Comment: To create user in a specific tenant, you need to authenticate to the SCIM end point using tenant's admin credentials (basic auth must be created with tenant user/password). But other parameters would be same as for super tenant.

Comment: can we add user to one existing primary group ??